# PHP jQuery aJax From responses and data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

not sure what im missing but im having a few issues with my code im trying to build.

- The data is not passing from the form to the database (blank entries)
- Its also going to repsonse.php and not staying on the forms page
- How can i pass the response for success and error back from response.php to the form to display on the frontend form?
- Lastly its adding the data twice (blank entries but twice all the same)

HTML

```
<form action="response.php" method="post" id="add_product">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_product">

    <div class="row">
        <div id="response" class="alert alert-success" style="display:none;">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <div class="message"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name" placeholder="Enter product name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_desc" placeholder="Enter product description">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><?php echo CURRENCY ?></span>
            <input type="text" id="product_price" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 margin-top btn-group">
        <input type="submit" id="action_add_product" class="btn btn-success float-right" value="Add product" data-loading-text="Adding...">
    </div>
</div>
```

RESPONSE.PHP

```
//check if any connection error was encountered
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Error: Could not connect to database.";
    exit;
}

$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : "";

// Adding new product
if($action == 'add_product') {

    $data = $_POST['serialize']; // serialize the data
    $product_name = $data['product_name'];
    $product_desc = $data['product_desc'];
    $product_price = $data['product_price'];

    //our insert query query
    $query  = "INSERT INTO products SET
                product_name = '".$product_name."', 
                product_desc = '".$product_desc."',
                product_price = '".$product_price."'
              ";

    //execute the query
    if($mysqli -> query($query)) {
        //if saving success
        echo "User was created.";
    } else {
        //if unable to create new record
        echo "Database Error: Unable to create record.";
    }
    //close database connection
    $mysqli -> close();
}
```

SCRIPTS.JS

```
// add product
    $('#action_add_product').click(function(){
        var $btn = $(this).button('loading');

        $.ajax({

            url: 'response.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#add_product').serialize(),
            success: function(result){
                $('#response .message').html('Product has been added successfully!');
                $('#response').fadeIn();
                $btn.button('reset');
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: My guess is the fact that you're missing the `name` attributes in your form inputs. Can you check your serialized formdata before posting: `console.log($('#add_product').serialize())` ?

Comment: I added name, did not fix it. Ill do a log and see what the results are.

Comment: action=add_product&product_name=&product_desc=&product_price=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The data is not passing from the form to the database (blank entries)

You're missing `name` attributes on your form inputs. Debugging the output of `$('#add_product').serialize()` verifies this.

> Its also going to repsonse.php and not staying on the forms page

You can set the form action to `#` (as Harigovind points out), I prefer to bind the `submit` event of the form instead, and prevent the default execution of the form. This also fixes the issue of people not pressing the button (firing your `click` event) but using the `enter` key instead:

```
$("#add_product").on("submit", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent default POST of form
   $.ajax({
      // etc
   });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/trL5t80w/

Comment: I have done like you said, much better with submit you are right. Ive added name attributes however they still dont seem to pass and unsure why.

Comment: action=add_product&product_name=&product_desc=&product_price=

Comment: Not sure why it's not working without seeing the code you changed. I've added a JSFiddle link where I can see the values being properly serialized

Answer (score 0):

Hi the issue you are facing is because your data is getting posted twice. Since you are using ajax you dont have to give form action. You can replace it by a '#' symbol.
 You can also use the jquery prevent default function to prevent the default posting of the form.

> Your echo in Response.php will act only as the response to athe ajax call so even if your database query is not executed the result will be you have successfully created the fields.

Also check if your serialized values are correct.

You can get the values of the serialized data just by replacing

```
$data = $_POST['serialize']; // serialize the data
$product_name = $data['product_name'];
$product_desc = $data['product_desc'];
$product_price = $data['product_price'];
```

these with

```
//$data = $_POST['serialize']; 
$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
$product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
```

Comment: That sorted things being added twice and moving to response.php file so 2 issues sorted thanks, how can i pass back the responses? any ideas? and thanks for your help.

Comment: Perfect that seems to have done the trick! do you know how i can pass back the success and error msg back to the <div id="response" class="alert alert-success"  and maybe set the class as well? then im all done :) thanks for your help

Comment: @james change your html("product has been added successfully ") with html ("result"). This will give you the  msg you have echoed in the php as ur html. Dont forget to accept this as answer since it solved your errors...

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting when you click on *#action_add_product* button. If you want use ajax, you can:

1. Change your *#action_add_product* element from `button` to `a` with *href='#'* - that prevent your form from being submitted
2. Change your js code `$('#action_add_product').click(function(){` to something like this: `$('#add_product').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `name` attribute of your fields. Any ajax request equivalent to $_GET or $_POST needs the fields.